# adding 7days to a date when copying from a google sheet to an other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

here is a code I have done to copy and organise data from a spreadsheet to an other one.

```
function GENERAL() {
  var Cop = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GO");
  var LP = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_Test-LISTE PROJETS");
  var values = LP.getRange('A4:V' + LP.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var res = values.flatMap(valueRange =>
    [
      [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[20], 'duréé projet' /**color red*/],//project lenght
      [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[17], 'phase de conception'/**color BLUE*/],//research lenght
      [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[17], valueRange[17]/**+ ' 7days'*/ , 'attente retour BAT'/**color white*/],//waiting for client
      [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[17] /**+ ' 7days'*/, valueRange[19], 'phase de fabrication'/**color green*/],//production time
      [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[19], valueRange[20], 'phase installation'/**color purple*/]//installation on site
    ]
  );
  Cop.getRange(2, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);

}
```

as mentionned on the tittle, the problem is that I want to add 7 days to some of the date :
"valueRange[17]/**+ ' 7days'*"
But I just don't know how...
Thanks for your help !

Comment: About `I still wanted to be able to use [17]`, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't notice it. So, I added a modified script to my answer. In my modification, a variable of `temp` is used. By the way, when `valueRange[177]` is used, `valueRange[0].length` is changed from `22` to `178` in the case of your script. So, when you use `valueRange` in another part of your script, the script might be required to be modified. Please be careful about this.

Comment: About your new issue of `valueRange[17].getTime is not a function`, I have already mentioned it in my answer. And, I updated my script. Please confirm my answer. By this modification, the value with no date object is skipped. But, I cannot know your Spreadsheet. If this was not your expected result, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: it's perfectly working ! thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to add 7 days to the value of `valueRange[17]` in your script.
- I suppose that your value of `valueRange[17]` is the date object.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
var res = values.flatMap(valueRange =>
  [
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[20], 'duréé projet' /**color red*/],//project lenght
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[17], 'phase de conception'/**color BLUE*/],//research lenght
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[17], valueRange[17]/**+ ' 7days'*/ , 'attente retour BAT'/**color white*/],//waiting for client
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[17] /**+ ' 7days'*/, valueRange[19], 'phase de fabrication'/**color green*/],//production time
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[19], valueRange[20], 'phase installation'/**color purple*/]//installation on site
  ]
);
```

#### To:

```js
var res = values.flatMap(valueRange => {
  valueRange[17] = new Date(valueRange[17].getTime() + (7 * 86400000));
  return [
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[20], 'duréé projet' /**color red*/],//project lenght
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[17], 'phase de conception'/**color BLUE*/],//research lenght
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[17], valueRange[17]/**+ ' 7days'*/, 'attente retour BAT'/**color white*/],//waiting for client
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[17] /**+ ' 7days'*/, valueRange[19], 'phase de fabrication'/**color green*/],//production time
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[19], valueRange[20], 'phase installation'/**color purple*/]//installation on site
  ];
});
```

#### Note:

- When an error like `valueRange[17].getTime is not a function` occurs, I think that the value of `valueRange[17]` is not the date object. In that case, can you provide the sample value of `valueRange[17]`?

### Added:

From `I still wanted to be able to use [17]`, in this case, how about the following modification? The converted value from `valueRange[17]` is put to `temp`.

#### To:

```js
var res = values.flatMap(valueRange => {

  // var temp = new Date(valueRange[17].getTime() + (7 * 86400000));
  var temp = valueRange[17] instanceof Date ? new Date(valueRange[17].getTime() + (7 * 86400000)) : valueRange[17];

  return [
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[20], 'duréé projet' /**color red*/],//project lenght
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], temp, 'phase de conception'/**color BLUE*/],//research lenght
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[17], temp/**+ ' 7days'*/, 'attente retour BAT'/**color white*/],//waiting for client
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], temp /**+ ' 7days'*/, valueRange[19], 'phase de fabrication'/**color green*/],//production time
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[19], valueRange[20], 'phase installation'/**color purple*/]//installation on site
  ];
});
```

- About your new issue of `valueRange[17].getTime is not a function`, I have already mentioned it in my answer. For this, I updated the above script. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ! it helps, it was almost what I need, cause I still wanted to be able to use [17]

so I modify your code just a little bit :

```
function GENERAL() {
  var Cop = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GO");
  var LP = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_Test-LISTE PROJETS");
  var values = LP.getRange('A4:V' + LP.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var res = values.flatMap(valueRange => {
  valueRange[177] = new Date(valueRange[17].getTime() + (7 * 86400000));
  return [
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[20], 'duréé projet' /**color red*/],//project lenght
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[17], 'phase de conception'/**color BLUE*/],//research lenght
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[17], valueRange[177], 'attente retour BAT'/**color white*/],//waiting for client
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[177], valueRange[19], 'phase de fabrication'/**color green*/],//production time
    [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[19], valueRange[20], 'phase installation'/**color purple*/]//installation on site
  ];
});
  Cop.getRange(2, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
```

know, it's perfecly doing what I need ! Thanks !

Comment: If it helped solving your issue, please upvote and/or mark Tanaike's as an answer